# crash scenario in Remote Direct Memory Access (RDMA)

Tags: memory, crash, rdma

My question is quite simple: If a machine's CPU/OS fails, is its memory still usable via Remote Direct Memory Access (RDMA) from remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the kind of failure the system is experiencing. If the OS fails, it is possible that an HCA implementing RDMA can continue performing DMA on behalf of remote requests. It won't be possible though to register new memory without OS and OS driver cooperation.

If the CPU fails, it might be impossible for the HCA to access memory, as all memory accesses go through the PCIe root complex and the memory controller on the CPU.